# How to create a global var inside jQuery Slider function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a slider inside my script:

```
var uniquePrice;
$( "#slider-secondary" ).slider({
  range: "min",
  value: 0,
  min: 0,
  max: 50,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#amount-secondary" ).val( ui.value );
            uniquePrice = ui.value * 1500;
  }
});
console.log(uniquePrice);
```

And I need to use the uniquePrice var further in the code, outside of the slider function. And it doesn't work - console.log(uniquePrice); says "undefined".

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. Of course I defined the global variable before the function, sorry for forgetting to include here.

Comment: where are you doing the console.log() call?

Comment: Right after the function, added the line to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the variable outside of the function.

```
var uniquePrice;
$( "#slider-secondary" ).slider({
      range: "min",
      value: 0,
      min: 0,
      max: 50,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
          $( "#amount-secondary" ).val( ui.value );
          uniquePrice = ui.value * 1500;
          console.log(uniquePrice);
      }
});
```

if you want the variable outside of the function you can do:

```
var uniquePrice;
$( "#slider-secondary" ).slider({
      range: "min",
      value: 0,
      min: 0,
      max: 50,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
          $( "#amount-secondary" ).val( ui.value );
          uniquePrice = ui.value * 1500;
          doLog();
      }
});

function doLog(){
    console.log(uniquePrice);
}
```

edit: added the console.log to the slider function

Comment: This would be the best, but you can also do `window.uniquePrice`.

Comment: i was unaware of that, very useful. in my way of thinking your way would seem better because then the variable would not have to be declared globally, but could still be used withen any scope

Comment: I did right the same, I just didn't include this line, edited the question. The result is the same - console.log(uniquePrice); says "undefined".

Comment: you need to put `console.log(uniquePrice);` inside of the slide function. look at my edited answer

Comment: I understand, that inside the function the console.log(); works. But I need to use the value of the var uniquePrice after the slider function later in my script to count total price.

Comment: Thanks, that works. Now I think I understand how to use the var further in my script.

Answer (score 1):

The console.log() is going to be called before that variable is set by that function. The js will:

- declare the var
- then setup the slider
- the immediately call console.log()

So until the slide happens that variable will be undefined

Comment: The var is undefined also after I move the slider.

I didn't understand exactly what you've ment, could you please give an example of the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think I read somewhere that if you forget to put the 'var' infront of the name of the variable, it gets declared as a global variable. Please confirm or deny this ;)

P.S. What happens if you remove line #1 altogether? What kind of error do you get?